# Difference between $C_0^{\infty}(U)$ with support in $A$ and $C_0^{\infty}(A)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, terminology

Let $A \subseteq U$ be open sets of $\mathbb R^n$. Is it true that
$$ \lbrace f \in C_0^{\infty}(A) \rbrace = \lbrace f \in C_0^{\infty}(U) : \text{support of } f \subseteq A \rbrace \quad ? $$
I recently attended a lecture where the speaker was using the rightmost set, and was wandering if for simplicity he couldn't replace it with the leftmost formulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify both sets very easily, but they aren't the same. A function $f \in C_0^\infty(U)$ with support in $A$ is a function on $U$ (not only on $A$), it is zero outside $A$, but nonetheless it is defined there. A function in $C^\infty_0(A)$ is only defined on $A$.

For the identification: The map $f\mapsto f|_A$ is an isomorphism from your right set to your left one.